# How to stop Vista changing folder views?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer

In Windows Vista, I've set the "list view" to apply to all folders under folder options. This works fine until I change the view of any *one* folder to something else (say, extra large thumbnails).

Then suddenly, every folder uses that extra large view. But if I switch it back to list view, this never gets applied for all folders - they're still using the extra large view.

Obviously I can go to folder options AGAIN and apply list view to all folders AGAIN, but it makes no sense why this happens in the first place. Changing the view once applies it to all folders, but doing exactly the same again doesn't... is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Try saving this to a file.reg and importing it, this should resolve your issue if I understand it correctly.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local     Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell]
"FolderType"="NotSpecified"
```

Answer (score -1):

http://mypchell.com/guides/15-make-vista-folder-view-settings-qstickq

I hope this helps.

Comment: That appears to be a way to set everything the same, but that's not what most people want.  Rather they just want, when they set their VacationPictures directory to show medium icons and their JavaSource directory to show details, to not come back later and find those settings swapped.